# Create very small range inside a very big word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I've pasted here the middle part of the bigger code, just so you guys can see the biger portion of it, but the line that's giving me some issues is in the second part, and is as follows: `Set wordRng2 = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(parNmbr).Range(Start:=startPos, End:=endPos)`.

There is a very big document, that have like 200 paragraphs.
Therefore using `wordRng.SetRange Start:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(parNmbr).Range.Start, End:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(parNmbr).Range.End` I'm extracting 23rd paragraph and I make range out of it.
In this paragraph, there is a data, that I'm after. 
It's a date, but written with a month as a word, in Polish, so its hard to extract using word wildcards.

I have some constant words, that are always in the same place in this paragraph. I assign them to `textToFind1` and `textToFind2` variables.

The string I want to extract from this paragraph is right between these two variables - maybe with a single space in the beginning and a trailing space in the end as well, but its there.

```
With wordRng.Find
      .Text = "<[A-Z]{3} [0-9]{6}>"            'you can use the tags < and > to mark the start and end of a word, respectively.
      .MatchWildcards = True     'these wildcards refer to polish ID number that is: ABC 123456 or BCF 765432 - it works fine;
      .MatchCase = False           'this part of the code works fine;
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Forward = True
      .Execute
      If .Found = True Then
        idNmbr = wordRng
        idNmbr = Trim$(idNmbr)
        intCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.match("nr_dokumentu", Worksheets("data").Range("1:1"), 0)    'Range("1:1") is row 1.
        mySheet.Cells(lngRow, intCol) = idNmbr                                                              'lngRow = lngRow + 1.
      End If
   End With

   'InStr function returns a Variant (Long) specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.
   wordRng.SetRange Start:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(parNmbr).Range.Start, End:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(parNmbr).Range.End
   Debug.Print wordRng
   startPos = InStr(1, wordRng, textToFind1) - 1                  'here we get 217, we're looking 4 id validity date;
   endPos = InStr(startPos, wordRng, textToFind2) - 1             'here we get 247, we're looking 4 id validity date;
   Set wordRng2 = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(parNmbr).Range(Start:=startPos, End:=endPos)            'Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=pos, End:=pos2)
   'Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment error.
   'at the moment "wordRng2" variable holds long date with month written as a word = października, listopada, grudnia;
   Debug.Print wordRng
   Debug.Print wordRng2
   wordRng2 = Trim$(wordRng2)
   Debug.Print wordRng2
```

I set second range variable, that's supposed to hold exactly the string I need to extract, with a possible trailing space in the end. But the line I use to do it: `Set wordRng2 = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(parNmbr).Range(Start:=startPos, End:=endPos)` returns "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" error.

In the example I'm trying it on, it should have 18 or 19 characters.

[image]

Even if I change this erroneous line into:

```
Set wordRng2 = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(parNmbr).Range            
wordRng2.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=endPos
```

still I get the string between 217 and 247 position from the beginning of the whole document and not the string between those values in the 23rd paragraph.

Comment: [`Paragraph.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraph.range) doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: So how to extract the little portion of text from this 23rd paragraph? I cannot use absolute `startPos` and `endPos` numbers, because in the earlier paragraphs these words also appear. The ones assigned to the `textToFind1` and `textToFind2` variables. 
I need to extract what is between those words but inside 23rd paragraph, not between those words in earlier paragraphs.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info on the structure of the string you’re actually trying to extract (I wasn’t sure if it was *just* a Polish month name or that name + something else. Perhaps some examples of things that would match and things that would not? Also, could there be a string with the same structure in the same paragraph but *outside* the area marked by textToFind1 & TextToFind2

Comment: First paragraph of the code works fine. The problem is with the second half of the code. Here I'll provide a bit more info on the structure of the string I'm actually trying to extract, so you could adjust the wildcards: `05 lipca 2018` or `14 października 1985` or `29 września 1999` - there are Polish letters there. This is what I think: day: `[0-9]{2}`, month is always one word, with variable nmbr of letters: `[a-z]{don't know what's here?}`, year: `[0-9]{4}`. Help me combine these parts into one wildcards expression. " " between day, month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, you need nothing more complex than:

```
With wordapp.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(23).Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<[0-9]{1,2} [cgklmpsw][airtuwz][eijprstuyzź]*> [0-9]{4}>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then MsgBox .Text
End With
```

Comment: maybe I wasn't that specific in my problem description - I've added two comments to the first block of code, if you care to check them. Here I'll provide a bit more info on the structure of the string I'm actually trying to extract, so you could adjust the wildcards: `05 lipca 2018` or `14 października 1985` or `29 września 1999` - there are Polish letters there. This is what I think: day: [0-9]{2}, month is always one word, with variable nmbr of letters: [a-z]{don't know what's here?}, year: [0-9]{4}. Help me combine these parts into one wildcards expression. " " between day, month and year.

Comment: «maybe I wasn't that specific in my problem description». No, that wasn't it. Rather, your problem description - especially where your Find expression is concerned - was misleading. See updated answer.

Comment: Why such a complicated wildcard expression?  `[cgklmpsw][airtuwz][eijprstuyzź]*>`  Please share a link where I could read more about it and understand. And where is missing `<` sign, because I can see two closing `>` but only one opening `<`.

Comment: The three strings bounded by [] represent all the possible letter combinations for each of the first 3 characters of a Polish month name. See: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm